# Security Context which is set in ContainerRequestFilter is null in Resources

Tags: security, jax-rs

To enable some security context be available for further processing in a Resource
I use the following advice [Access object created in ContainerRequestFilter in Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599655/access-object-created-in-containerrequestfilter-in-resources) but get Security Context null.

**ContainerRequestFilter**

```
@Override
public synchronized void filter(ContainerRequestContext request)
        throws IOException {

    final User user = authorizationValidation.isAuthorizationValid(userHeader)

    // impl 
    request.setSecurityContext( new MySecurityContext(user) );

    // or simple but not the best
    request.setSecurityContext( new SecurityContext() {
        @Override
        public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
            return true; // check roles if you need ...
        }
        @Override
        public boolean isSecure() {
            return false; // check HTTPS
        }
        @Override
        public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
            return user; // return your user here - User must implement Principal
        }
        @Override
        public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
            return null; // ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Resource**

```
    @GET
    @Secured
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(value="text/plain")
    public String test(@Context SecurityContext context)  
    {
        // my logic where context == null
    }
```

I also tried to declare the class member like

```
@Context
protected SecurityContext securityContext;
```

but also got it null

Please explain me what I'm missing in my code.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check to see if the filter is even being called?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was my miss, @Context SecurityContext context was import with wrong class. when set it to be import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext, the context was passed successfully